# Troubleshooting Android 6 screencast to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, android, screencasts

As I have unlimited mobile data only (not for tethering), but no landline, it makes sense to use my mobile for online meetings or watching films.

However my TV has a more convenient screen size.
I can connect the PC to the TV and I'd then cast the phone screen to the PC via WiFi.

So I got hold of the "Connect" app from Microsoft and switched on casting on my Android 6 phone.

The first time it worked a treat. Unfortunately it never worked since. The PC and phone both appear to start connecting, but the PC reverts to how it was before trying and the phone claims it is connecting. Nothing more happens.

Sometimes I think we are going backwards with oversimplified programs or apps - the Connect app has no visible settings, logging or error messages, same for the Android cast option.

How does one find out what the problem is with these silent programs? Phone is Ulefone Power if relevant. Same issue with Lenovo P2. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the Connect app isn't working, try another one. Here is a site with a few suggestions; it also has app descriptions and step-by-step instructions for installation and use.  The downloads are also linked on the site.

[Suggested ways to cast Android to PC](https://showmore.com/cast-android-screen-to-pc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Setting for projecting to Windows PC are given at - All Settings -> System -> Projecting to this PC.
Try removing your Android device from Devices in Windows.